# Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean"

Tags: string, azure-devops, yaml, boolean, azure-pipelines

I am trying to put a variable inside a parameter in the pipeline yml for the Azure DevOps. I am trying to do it like so:

```
variables:
  myArg: true

- template: my-custom-template.yml@myrep
  parameters:
    myArg: $[ eq(variables.argVal, 'true') ]
```

But I am getting the error:

> $[ eq(variables.argVal, 'true') ]

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter
> | 'myArg'. Cannot convert value "System.String" to type
> | "System.Boolean". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and
> | numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.

Instead of the `$[ eq(variables.argVal, 'true') ]` I tried the `${{ eq(variables.argVal, 'true') }}` and the `$( eq(variables.argVal, 'true') )`. All gave the same error.

So, could someone help me to understand what is the correct way to convert a variable to a boolean parameter in Azure DevOps pipeline yml, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use parameters with runtime expressions (`$[]`). Parameters are resolved at template compilation time, before runtime expressions can be evaluated. You should use compilation expressions, `${{}}`